# video streaming(youtube) in 3D environment(game)?

Tags: video, youtube, 3d, streaming, direct3d

I want to upload a video to streaming service (like Youtube) and want to play it in my game.

I don't actually need it for "real 3D" like rotate or scale it.

I need it for main screen or lobby. It is 3D accelerated environment but looking 2d. (you know what I mean)

Is there any library does that or if none, how can I make it? (please just give me some guide)

Thank you.

Comment: You could parse the youtube link (page) to find the actual video URL, there are opensource solutions for this. After that you can stream the mp4 video using Media Foundation and use it to fill a D3D11 or D3D9 texture for you.

Comment: @VuVirt Thank you for comment. But I failed to find the opensource solution. Can you give me any example solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Please check this example solution: https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor